# Wordpress Add custom permalink

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have a dynamic page setup in wordpress which uses a `$_GET['id']` php variable to make a query to the database. The problem is that my url format looks like the following:

> http://site.com/business/id?=123

What's the best way to make the url look like:

> http://site.com/business/business-name-here

Is it done using rewrite rules in the .htaccess file?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found a great class to do just that by Kyle E try it.

```
<?php
/*
//Author Kyle E Gentile
//To use this class you must first include the file.  
//After including the file, you need to create an options array.  For example:
$options = array(
    'query_vars' => array('var1', 'var2'),
    'rules' => array('(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&var1=$matches[2]&var2=$matches[3]')
);
//After creating our $option array, 
//we will need to create a new instance of the class as below:
$rewrite = new Add_rewrite_rules($options);
//You must pass the options array, this way. (If you don't there could be problems) 
//Then you can call the filters and action functions as below:
add_action('wp_head', array(&$rewrite, 'flush_rules'));
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$rewrite, 'add_rewrite_rules') );
add_filter( 'query_vars', array(&$rewrite, 'add_query_vars') );
//That is it.
*/

//prevent duplicate loading of the class if you are using this in multiply plugins
if(!class_exists('add_rewrite_rules')){

    class Add_rewrite_rules{

        var $query_vars;
        var $rules;

        function __construct($options){
            $this->init($options);
        }

        function init($options){
            foreach($options as $key => $value){
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }

        function rules_exist(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            $has_rules = TRUE;

            foreach($this->rules as $key => $value){
                if(!in_array($value, $wp_rewrite->rules)){
                    $has_rules = FALSE;
                }   
            }

            return $has_rules;
        }

        //to be used add_action with the hook 'wp_head'
        //flushing rewrite rules is labor intense so we better test to see if our rules exist first
        //if the rules don't exist flush its like after a night of drinking  
        function flush_rules(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            if(!$this->rules_exist()){
                //echo "flushed"; // If want to see this in action uncomment this line and remove this text and you will see it flushed before your eyes
                $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
            }
        }

        //filter function to be used with add_filter() with the hook "query_vars"
        function add_query_vars($query_vars){

            foreach($this->query_vars as $var){
                $query_vars[] = $var;
            }

            return $query_vars;
        }

        //to be used with a the add_action() with the hook "generate_rewrite_rules"
        function add_rewrite_rules(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            $wp_rewrite->rules = $this->rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Add the following function to the init of your plugin / functions file.

```
public function rewriteRules()
{
//Add the query variables to the list so wordpress doesn't discard them or worse use them to try and find by itself what page to serve.
    $options = array(
        'query_vars' => array('trainingid', 'vakname'),
        'rules' =>
            array( 'uncategorized/vak/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?p=1316&vakname=$matches[1]&level=$matches[2]'
            )
    );

    //I use a autoloader but if you don't you have to include the class.
    //include_once('path/to/AddRewriteRules.php');
    $rewrite = new AddRewriteRules($options);
    add_action('wp_head', array(&$rewrite, 'flush_rules'));
    add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$rewrite, 'add_rewrite_rules'));
    add_filter('query_vars', array(&$rewrite, 'add_query_vars'));


}
```